# PHP + mysql - left join - three tables

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I've got a weird question. I have three tables:
- table_a with columns (id, product_id, customer_id, location, phone)
- table_b with columns (id, product_id, product_name)
- table_c with columns (id, customer_id, customer_name)

What I would like to display is a table with following content:
table_a.id, product_name, customer_name, location, phone

So I assume somehow I should use left join table_b, table_c with table_a.

I've tried multiple approaches like:

```
SELECT*FROM table_a INNER JOIN table_b, table_c
ON table_a.product_id = table_b.product_id
ON table_a.customer_id = table_c.customer_id
```

I want to avoid making duplicates of product_id/customer_id in final table..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the other fields, but which id are you trying to get? All 3 tables have id field.

Assuming you can take the id of first table:

```
SELECT table_a.id, table_b.product_name as product_name, table_c.customer_name as customer_name, table_a.location as location, table_a.phone as phone

FROM table_a INNER JOIN table_b

ON table_a.product_id = table_b.product_id

INNER JOIN table_c

ON table_a.customer_id = table_c.customer_id
```

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD

Comment: It's weird. I've used your scheme - here is the query: codepad.org/Z7HY5LEn but when i'm trying this query even via phpmyadmin Im getting 1064 error - it points out that on last three lines there is an error. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

You need to join sequently table_a with table_b to get product_name, then table_a with table_c to get customer_name. You can try with this:

```
SELECT table_a.id, product_name, customer_name, location, phone
FROM table_a 
    INNER JOIN table_b ON table_a.product_id = table_b.product_id
    INNER JOIN table_c ON table_a.customer_id = table_c.customer_id
```

Answer (score 2):

It can help to specify the table name prior to the table attribute in your select statement. Hope this helps!

```
select
    table_a.id,
    table_b.product_name,
    table_c.customer_name,
    table_a.location,
    table_a.phone
from table_a
left join table_b
    on table_a.product_id = table_b.product_id
left join table_c
    on table_a.customer_id = table_c.customer_id
```

Comment: do you know any specific PHP class or script which can use PDO to display large amount of data? everytime when I do that, im getting 500 error. What is more weird - my code: http://codepad.org/7HGBxmkq used in phpmyadmin - create a table with repeated fields.. e.g. my row with ID #1, is copied about 150 times?

Comment: I use Laravel for most of my projects, so mostly using eloquent for any DB interaction - I believe it uses PDO. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent If you're getting a 500 error it's probably because of a timeout, try to limit your query to 10 rows to see if it works and if it does change your php settings to allow more than 30 secs for your query to execute. In any case you may want to consider pagination of results instead of spitting out a huge load of data to the screen.

Comment: Better to ask another question if you're having further issues on a different query